# exported fbx doesn't play all of its animations

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, export, blender, fbx

I have a body I designed in blender. When I imported the .blend file into unity it worked just fine, but after I exported a fbx file it keeps playing only one of the body's parts animation. How can make it play them all together just as it happened with the blend file?

Comment: Did you bake the animations in blender before importing into Unity?

Comment: yes..but even if I go throuh the whole list of states and play them it performs only one of them.. @Programmer